# Prepare SMS message from an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, sms

Is it possible? Developers can use SMS URLs to populate the phone number, but I haven't found a way to populate the message body.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible currently. By requesting this feature from apple you are making chances better for it to appear soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This other look at the topic from before the NDA was lifted:

[How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

was unable to find a solution. "sms:" URLs work but no "body" tag is respected. As a suggestion, send a feature request to Apple. You won't be the first person to request this feature but despite their seeming silence, Apple do read each request.

Comment: I sent a request for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible via the iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.