# Can your iphone app interact with the modem and still be accepted by apple?

Tags: iphone, sms, modem

I don't want my app to probe the nether parts of the iPhone... just use the modem to send a simple SMS message.  Is this a deal-breaker with Apple?  Why?

I'm considering a workaround where outgoing SMS are routed to a URL I set up to bounce the message on to the intended recipient.  Do you think this is a feasible route to consider?

Comment: if its more the app rather than the platform you are excited about, Android has a nice API for sending SMS messages.

Comment: Very few phones with SDKs let you send direct modem commands, because of how that could screw with the primary function of the device.  Even Android doesn't seem to make using AT commands easy: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a7eb39bbdd01ecff

Answer (score 3):

[How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

basically, you can open the sms app but you'll have to route through an (internet-based) sms gateway if you don't want to leave your app to send it.

Comment: I was hoping to not leave the app and send messages directly using modem AT commands.
So, you think the internet-based workaround might bear fruit?

Comment: ...that is assuming modem AT commands would be poo pooed by Apple.

Comment: The rule with iphone apps seems to me to be "if you have to ask..."

Answer (score 1):

SMS may be limited by the phone operator. This is a no-go if the user doesn't know a SMS is being sent.

Besides, interacting with something low-level like a device seems to be something Apple wouldn't like.

I don't know enough about phone protocols to be of any other help, though.