# developing sms application in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

i am new to iPhone programming and i was thinking of developing an sms application through which user can send and receive sms inside my application similar to iPhone own message application.i think apple doesn't provide any API regarding accessing sms inbox?? is there any other way around it??

Comment: Nope. Apple keeps that for its self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible through the default iPhone SDK.

You have two possibilities:

1. Create an application through [Open Tool Chain](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=281). I'm not very experienced with this kind of developement, but I think it should be possible to access the SMS inbox etc from outside. Drawback: Only jailbroken phones, no App Store...
2. Create your own service that sends SMS via, for example, a server. You could use Push notifications or something to indicate when new messages has arrived. You should however be aware of, and read up on, Apple's guidelines regarding applications that imitate functionality of built in core applications.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the list of [new features in iPhone OS 4](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/iphone/whats-new.html) ("In-App SMS").

Can't help you regarding the actual API and what its limitations are, though.

Comment: This could be helpful. Apple docs for Messagecomposer. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MessageComposer/Introduction/Intro.html