# iphone sms application

Tags: iphone, sms

How to develop a sms app for iphone?

Are there any api available to develop this kind of app?

Is there any other way to develop this type of app for iphone apart from using api

Please suggest me some ideas..

Thanks

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832280/developing-sms-application-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, SMS can only be sent from the official SMS app.

You can only forward the user to the application. You may specify the phone number of the recipient. Unfortunately, you can't even specify the content of the SMS, so it's not of much use.

If you are interested : [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

If you are interested in how to design an application that looks like the SMS application, please specify this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for MFMessageComposeViewController. iOS 4.0 or later is required though.

On earlier OSes your best bet is to open an sms: URL. The URL scheme only allows you to specify the destination number, not the content of the message.