# framework for setting the sms body programmatically in iphone

Tags: iphone

i want to set the sms body by my application so there is any way or a framework available to do this task.. and if any framework than how to implement that.. 
plz help.  i searched a lot on google but all in vain...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

The public iPhone api does not support this functionality.

You are only able to trigger the preparation of an empty message to a phone number by using the `sms:[phone number]` url