# How to develop/code an application which could send sms from iPhone with text in it

Tags: objective-c, sms, iphone-sdk-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

How to develop/code an application which could send sms from iPhone with text in it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to send an sms message from your application. You could for example make an application that connects to your server and sends the message from there.

Comment: That's not so if you use iOS 4 sdk