# iphone - Sending SMS without quitting the application

Tags: iphone, sms

In iPhone app Development, we can use "openURL" to send SMS.
But the problem is that, the app quits and opens SMS application.
How can I send 10 different customized SMS to 10 different phone numbers without quitting application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do exactly that -- presumably to stop unscrupulous applications spamming your contact list.

You can allow a user to send an SMS without existing your application by using the [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/index.html), which is only available in iOS4. You can fill in the defaults but it's up to the user to press the "Send" button.

Answer (score 0):

in iOS4, you app will goto into the background, so it is possible that the app wont quit. 
I think you can also send the same message to 10 different people.

But to send 10 different messages, thats is a bit of spam engine, and apple dont allow things like this.