# Send SMS programmatically on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

I want to send sms programmatically.
I tried with the following code,It triggers message composer and then user needs to manually select the send button but I just want everything to be done programmatically that is even to send sms not only insert recipent number and body message.

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
 controller.body = @"Hello from Dinesh";
 controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"999468*****", @"91999468****", nil];
 controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
 [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Help me...

Answer (score 5):

Can't be done. The SDK does not allow automated SMSing, for obvious reasons—your app can ask the user to hit "Send", and that's really about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an in App tutorial for sending SMS. Must have user consent, though, so may not be the answer you are looking for.

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-how-to-send-in-app-sms/

Comment: Thanks Jordan...but in this tutorial only i found the code added above for which user has to select sms button manually....

Comment: Can't be done without user explicit consent.