# send sms programmatically on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sms

in my application I want to send predefine smstext to one single number on certain event ,
 how to send sms like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot send an SMS without user intervention. However, with the user's "approval" there are two ways to send an SMS from an iPhone application.

1. Apple's [MessageComposer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MessageComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010161) sample project has code that shows you how to send an SMS using the MFMessageComposeViewController class.
2. Alternatively, you can use:

   ```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:1-408-555-1212"]];
   ```