# Is it possible to send mass texts using iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

I'd like to be able to send text messages in my app on iOS. I know that I have to use the MessageUI framework. My question is if it is possible to automate the process, of sending, say 100 text messages at once, while modifying the message ever

Comment: You know that *that* will never pass Apple's Gestapo, and probably rightfully so.

Comment: Monty Pythons's Spam skit comes to mind....

Comment: No, think of this as a MailMerge kind of app.

Comment: Already answered (it appears) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone - see the answer from jus' wondrin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone apps have absolutely no access whatsoever to SMS (without using private auto-reject calls), no sending, no intercepting received messages, no reading what messages on on the device. You can set up messages for the user to send, but you can't send anything automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advise doing so.

But if you did, I would advise doing it through your own SMTP client, as opposed to using the Messaging UI.

SMTP is a very simple protocol, or you can use an existing library, like http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/

Comment: Would this require a separate server, or can I just use the phone's text messaging plan?