# Sending SMS via iPhone5

Tags: php, iphone, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

Has anyone succeeded to send SMS using php script or whatever (programmatically) via own iPhone5 and how? Iphone4 seems to lack support for programmatic sending without jailbreaking.

Comment: This was never possible, it's currently not possible neither will it be possible in the future, becsuse it would enable spam. You can only send SMSes using MFMessageComposeViewController.

Comment: What is MFMessageComposeViewController?

Comment: An objectiveC method in the iPhone SDK (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @JasonSperske close enough... It's a class, not a method.

Comment: duplicate of: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone>, <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516132/how-can-i-send-sms-programmatically-in-iphone>, <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859215/sending-sms-programatically-in-iphone>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you can trigger via webkit which is the only way PHP can interact with the iPhone.  As for firing an SMS, you can always use an [email gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways) (you will need to know the carrier of the number you are trying to send the message to), or you can use something like [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms) which makes sending (and responding to) SMS extremely easy (even from PHP).

Comment: Is Twilio not email gateway? Have you used Twilio self? Do they charge for failed messages (eg. wrong recipient)?

Comment: I do use Twilio (I made this: http://vgpedia.net, checkout the phone number) as well as some other services that both send and respond to SMS, it's really cool).  They charge for each attempt, even if you have the wrong number then.  They are like an email gateway but they use a REST interface and remove the need to know which carrier owns the number.  A good pattern to limit the chance of using a wrong number is to have the user send a text message to your Twilio number.  This will capture their phone number (similar to caller ID) and act as a confirming step.