# How do I generate an SMS message based on a template in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, sms

I'm trying to make an iPhone app where a user can use a built-in template for sending SMS messages.  For example:

> Dear [recipient name]
>
> I would like to meet you.
>
> Yours sincerely,
>
> [recipient name]

I want to change `[recipient name]` to the person the user is sending the SMS message to.

How would I generate the string to be sent in the SMS message, and how would I send it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if any one looking for the code i have done it myself.

if (appdelegate.dataarray.count>0) {
                NSMutableArray *dataarrrr = [appdelegate.dataarray objectAtIndex:0];
                NSLog(@"%@",[dataarrrr objectAtIndex:0]);
                NSString *aa = [dataarrrr objectAtIndex:0];
                NSMutableArray *myArray = [aa componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

```
            NSString *n = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *m=[myArray objectAtIndex:1];
            NSString *Message = [dataarrrr objectAtIndex:1];
            NSString *new = [Message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<Dear User>" withString:n];
            controller.body = new;
            controller.recipients= [NSArray arrayWithObject:m];
            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html), you can set the SMS body before displaying the message composer. I don’t think there’s a better way to send text messages, see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848).

Comment: the problem is that u can not change the body of the sms after u click the name of recipient. i want to change body of sms after i select a person whom i wanted to send sms.

Comment: @Syed if you want that, then present the address book yourself, preset the body and have at it. No way apple is gonna let you programmatically modify a message that user thinks she's sending after the fact.