# Missed Call Alert

Tags: iphone

I wish to implement sending pre-defined sms templates to missed call numbers automatically on iPhone. How can I do this?

Comment: I am sure that given that you have had a dig around the documentation that you would be able to tie into a missed call event being raised as well as easy documentation on sending SMSs.

i.e.
How to send an SMS programmatically 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for this in the official SDK.

Any apps that do this will not be accepted into the App Store.

Your only option would be to jailbreak the phone and do it there.