# How send messages to the contact list numbers

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, sms, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am working in new application and I am new to iphone.

I want to send a message to the person whom I have added from the contact list.

Is it possible?

Can you please give me some sample code or links.

Answer (score 0):

For sending SMS through iPhone, it is required to have user authentication. So programmatically without and user interaction you cannot send an SMS

You need to see this to get a better idea:

[How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

also see:

**[MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)**

Comment: Yes you are correct but If I am not wrong, it is not possible to send SMS without user authentication.

Comment: @PARTH: You're totally correct, it's mentioned in the First link it's not possible.