# send message from iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

Is it possible to send text messages from an iphone app automatically through code. I havent seen any sample code of this yet?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support from Apple in the original SDK to do automatic sending. I mean, the support that exists in the official SDK - the MessageUI framework - allows you to send text messages, but you can't escape the UI that Apple imposes, and you can't send the messages automatically.

But what you can do is to use a 3rd party service. I've been using clickatell.com for about 6 years now ( vb6 and .net too :) ... ) - and i only can recommend it ... 
You could give a go with them ?