# current location with map

Tags: iphone, sms, mkmapview, userlocation

hai
     I am creating an application. I want to sent the users current location with map using gps and without gps as sms. Is it possible?
Please help me if anybody knows. Give some sample tutorial or code.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take screen shot of mapview  through the following code and send multimedia SMS through the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

```
 - (UIImage *)captureView:(UIView *)view 
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);

  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  [[UIColor blackColor] set];
  CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

  [view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

   UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return newImage;
}
```