# How to send SMS programmatically using UDID without cost in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sms, message

I want to know is it possible to send SMS programmatically using Objective-C in iPhone using UDID means that the TO address should be an UDID of the other iPhone than phone number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

Comment: You should use push notification

Comment: @DarkDust The question is something different

Comment: @KingofBliss: You're right, I missed the subtle *"TO address should be an UDID of the other iphone"* part.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send an SMS to another phone that you only know by UDID. An SMS always needs a phone number as address.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. OK by using phone number, can we able to send sms through app without any cost.

Comment: Whether the user has to pay for SMS depends on his mobile contract and is beyond your reach. If there were any generic way to send gratis SMS everyone would be doing it, right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the UDID then you can send Push Notification using your own server.

***THIS WILL ALLOW THE USER TO CHAT WITHIN YOUR APPLICATION.***

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

First SMS works with phone numbers, zo not a UDID.

The User will also be charged for sending a SMS and you can only send a SMS via de [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html). There is not way to do it in code only.