# Message API in iOS

Tags: ios, email, sms, message

I wonder if there is an API for sending message (SMS and mail) in iOS without having to use a view controller? I don't want the user to be able to edit the message.

Comment: This is why Apple don't allow anything developer want to do in the App Store. I don't think you will be able to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot send SMS/Email without user acceptance. But there are a lot of web-services in internet which can send SMS/Email. I guess some app uses those services or uses own.

See also: [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)