# send sms using ipad through my Own application

Tags: ios5, sms, ipad-3

I am building a system in iOS on ipad which records appointments. Once a appointment is scheduled, a message needs to be sent to the number given while scheduling. Is there a way i can send a SMS through ipad?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/59200/365188

Comment: Shouldn't be any different than on iPhone. The UIMessage framework is your friend :)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendinganSMSMessage.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

Comment: @OzairKafray I went through all the links you provided. I helped. But all say that it is not possible for ipad. I require it for ipad with ios5. Any other link can be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to send an SMS while remaining in the app on iOS.

You could allow the user to send an SMS by tapping an element which would bring up the messages app and allow you to send one there, but not in the app itself.

You could however, use your own solution in Obc-C (or written in another language such as PHP) which sends the messages through a message gateway.

An example would be this:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-send-text-messages-with-php/