# How to send SMS with Some Body text programmatically in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sms, send

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

How to Send SMS with Some Body text programmatically from iPhone using Objective-C.
Was trying to do something like:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sms:?&body:%@", aSMSBodyText];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url];
```

but not working, I don't want to use MFMessageComposeViewController, cause my app supports from 3.0 Onwards & MFMessageComposeViewController is applicable from 4.0 Onwards.

Comment: use the [MFMessageComposer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) class for this job

Comment: check out the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/sms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008054-SW1 you can't assign a "body"

Answer (score 2):

You can not send SMS without the use of MFMessageComposeViewController. if you want to send SMS, then you have to use MFMessageComposeViewController. Otherwise, you can use server to use SMS. First you need to send message to server and then server will send message to any number.
You can also use SMS gateway for sending SMS.