# How to send a message in iPhone devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, send, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Currently i am working in iPhone application, Using MFMessageComposeViewController to develop this application and its working fine.

[image]

But i want, message compose screen don't show on the screen, then the Message send programmatically ,
How to do this? it is possible? please help me

I tried this:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = @"Hi"; 
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12345678", @"87654321", nil];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Check this post:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to do this once but but it wont be accepted by app store. Apple wont let you send message/email without user knowledge about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sms:[target phone number] URL to open the SMS application, but there are no indications on how to prefill a SMS body with text (see [this post](https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?appIdKey=4a75046cda87eab6386a9eae8caabb9824e328b9abc988119b39296495ec184c&path=/login.jspa) on Apple Developer Forums).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the Message Framework to send a message without the user knowing about it. One common solution is to send the message details to a web service running on your server and send the message from the server. As long as you're not trying to be sneaky, I don't think there's anything wrong with doing that.