# Sending SMS programatically in IOS 6?

Tags: ios6, message

How to programatically send a pre-composed message from IOS 6,
Experts are appreciated even for there replies, am in a critical situation please help me to find out a solution, i am ready with my app till IOS 5 and please help me to move on IOS 6.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import MessageUI.framework to your project.

Anyways, it has already been answered [here - How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone). Check Najeebullah Shah's answer. It should work with the latest SDK.

Comment: it works well with IOS 5 i need it to be worked with IOS 6 and thank for your head's up..