# Send SMS without presenting MessageComposeViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, sms

I am working on sending SMS demo. I want to send how to send the SMS and how to set the delegate to MessageComposeViewController. and in order to send the message we have below line

```
[self presentViewController:messageController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

This line will present the MessageComposeView on screen with SEND button. And Once we click on send button it sends the message. What I want is to send the message directly without presenting this MessageController on screen. Please help how can I do this.

Answer (score 2):

[In this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone), Apple has restrictions in place on being able to send a SMS message without the user clicking the SEND button.

Apple *really* wants the user to be in control of the SMS functionality of their phone.  Otherwise all sorts of data could be flying off some random app (e.g. spamming your contacts with "try this app out!", which would not be very friendly nor very nice).

[One of the answers in this question ***does*** have a potential non-MFMessageComposeViewController solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13063499/981049), however I have a feeling that if Apple catches you doing this they might deny your app from being approved for the app store.

Comment: I don't want to upload my app to appstore, I will be using inhouse. In that case, is there any way I can send the messages?

Comment: You could try that specific answer in the related question I linked to.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could send the message using some webservice on the internet. http://client.suresms.com/ProjectInfo.aspx?Info=3 or www.clickatell.com. They have bunches of API for sending messages.

In SureSMS simply create an account and make a http request to 
[http://suresms.com/Script/GlobalSendSMS.aspx?login=[youraccountnumber]&password=[yourpassword]&to=[phonenumber]&Text=Hallo](http://suresms.com/Script/GlobalSendSMS.aspx?login=%5byouraccountnumber%5d&password=%5byourpassword%5d&to=%5bphonenumber%5d&Text=Hallo).

Remember to URL encode the message text and use countrycodes. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to present MessageComposeViewController.It's not possible to send without presenting it.

MFMessageComposeViewController has delegate method while delete/send/save. which only perform while we present it.

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without MFMessageComposeViewController. Apple won't allow to send SMS without user interaction.

As per document

> You must not modify the view hierarchy presented by this view
>   controller. You can, however, customize the appearance of the
>   interface using the UIAppearance protocol.

I've alternate solution of this, Alternative way can be Using web service API. Create a web service at server side that send a message to specific number(s) that accept numbers as parameters with request.(according to your requirement)

As using Web server or external sms provider can do it.

Answer (score -1):

It is NOT possible . Apple willn't accept your App. Apple will reject your App if you do like that. Human interface guidelines should be followed up.