# how to send verification code by sms in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, sms

i build a register form for my app and i need to send the user a verifiation code by sms in order to complete the registration proccess.

i tried to use MFMessageComposeViewController but its open the dialog sms on the device so the user can see the code.

i also checked the web for 3party of sending sms but there is a problem with the country code. i know its posible becuse whatsapp do it to confirm the user.

what it the right way to do it?

this is the topic the i tried:
[Sending SMS in iOS with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350220/sending-sms-in-ios-with-swift/36513735?noredirect=1#comment60636616_36513735)

Comment: You should probably do this on your backend. iOS app submits a request to the backend. Backend generates a random code. Backend sends SMS to user. User enters in code. iOS app submits back to backend to verify. You can use a service like Twilio to send SMS messages (https://www.twilio.com/).

Answer (score 3):

The best way to achieve this is by creating some views for allowing the user to enter the phone number with the country code which can be used by a server to send a request for initiating the OTP verification. To achieve this you need to:

1. Create View Controllers.
2. Upload Phone Number and Country code to the server.
3. Validate the requests by verifying the OTP.

As mentioned by Dan, you can use [Digits](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/digits) in [Fabric](https://www.fabric.io/) for that purpose, and create custom views for a great UX.

On the other hand, you can also use a service called as [SendOTP](http://sendotp.msg91.com) from MSG91 - you can use it for internal testing and development ideas as they provide you with 5,000 free OTP SMS. The service has a complete set of APIs which you can implement on the backend as well on the app front. Also, they provide a [framework](https://github.com/SendOTP/iOS) so that you don't need to create the views, but only `presentViewController` and call `delegate` methods for knowing what happened during the verification process - such as `Cancelled` or `Verified` or `Failed`.

Swift implementation of the same looks like this:

```
    class OTPFrame: UIViewController, sendOTPAuthenticationViewControllerDelegate {    

   func loadOTPFramework() {
            SendOTP.sharedManager().startWithApiId("yourAppID")
            let frameworkPath: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().privateFrameworksPath!
            let frameworkBundlePath: NSString = frameworkPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("SendOTPFramework.framework")
            let frameworkBundle : NSBundle
                = NSBundle(path: frameworkBundlePath as String)!
            let authenticationViewController: AuthenticationViewController = AuthenticationViewController(nibName: "AuthenticationViewController", bundle: frameworkBundle)
            authenticationViewController.delegate = self                self.presentViewController(authenticationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func authenticationisSuccessfulForMobileNumber(mobNo: String!, withCountryCode countryCode: String!) {
            print("Success")
        }

        func canceledAuthentication() {
            print("Cancelled")
        }

        func authenticationisFailedForMobileNumber(mobNo: String!, withCountryCode countryCode: String!) {
            print("Failed")
        }
    }
```

Disclaimer: I, in no way, endorse the services mentioned above - you are free to choose whatever you like.

Thank You!

Comment: @NirTzin upvote and/or accept if you like :) .. Happy to help! - Fennec.

Comment: Try putting the checks at the crash point or try to look at the issues on their github repo.

Comment: Hi @Fennec! Both of the above services you mentioned aren't available, as I checked. It'd be great if you could mention some alternatives I could use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would give digits a try! It's part of the Twitter Fabric package and it's very simple to use. The user enters their phone number and Fabric takes care of validating the number.