# SWIFT & XCODE 7 : Click on a Button and Send SMS (not using the app Message)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I am developing a small app with the main goal is : send a SMS. But I would like to send this SMS without passing through the app Message. For instance, I click on a Button, I(body and recipient are already defined) sent SMS immediately without using the App Message.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You have to use: MFMessageComposeViewController
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350220/sending-sms-in-ios-with-swift

Comment: LViet : I have used this method and I passed through the app Message. For my case, I would like to avoid the app Message and send programmatically. Anyway thanks for your quick response.

Comment: If you want to send a message without user action then you need to use a 3rd party service such as Twilio or Sinch. You can't send it from the user's number; it will come from the number associated with the service and at your cost.

Comment: @Paulw11 : Thanks. I checked this way. So, if I understood, the matter is to use a web service which handle the SMS and I have to do a connection with.

Comment: That's right. For security/fraud prevention Apple doesn't allow you to send an SMS from the user without their interaction