# SMS Apps - Who pays ? Where is it coming from?

Tags: ios, sms

I know how to send the SMS with Swift (using `MFMessageComposeViewController`). But what I am wondering is 
how does it work? Where is the message coming from? And who pays the SMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SMS is sent and charged by your phone provider.
If the person you're sending it to has iMessage, it's free and handled by Apple.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense.

If the user enter a phone number (example : XXX YYY WWWW), the app has no acess  to the user's phone number (example : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39849652/7010252), but it still sends a SMS to XXX YYY WWWW

Comment: It's just like when you send a message from the messages app. If the number is wrong it fails to send or deliver

Comment: So this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39849652/7010252 wouldn't work ? Moreover if the code in the link works where is the user's phone number?

Comment: It works. It prompts a view just like when you compose a new message on the native app. You can pre set the recipients like this: controller.recipients = [phoneNumber] (right there on the code)

Comment: yeah but for your friend number not your own number, right?

Comment: Exactly. your own number depends on the SIM card you have on the phone, you can't fake it