# How to set recipient number in SMS activity from UIActivityController

Tags: ios, swift

I have to send invitation to specific number from `SMS` activity which is from `UIActivityController`. I searched about this but didn't see any code to set recipient for `SMS` activity in `UIActivityController`.

Comment: What do you mean by send invitation?

Comment: You can try this outing MessageUI framework.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350220/sending-sms-in-ios-with-swift

Comment: @PGDev I need to set recipient for SMS activity which is opened from UIActivityController. Is there any way to do it from UIActivityController?

Comment: This is a great question that should be answered.