# Send a text message when UISwitch is toggled

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to send an automatic text message to a preset number when a UISwitch is toggled off using Swift, so that a user could be alerted if the app was disabled?

Comment: not possible w/o jailbreaking, needs user interaction

Comment: You can't with the in-built messaging capabilities. You could integrate a 3rd party messaging service.

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

**No.**

## Long Answer

Unfortunately it is not. Not automatically, but you can:

1. Schedule a [Local Notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) with the desired frequency.
2. When the user clicks the notification use [MessageUI](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008274)'s [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MFMessageComposeViewController/canSendText).

**Warning**: don't forget to check if the device `MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()`

To send an SMS using MFMessageComposeViewController you simply have to:

- Set the `body`
- Set the `recipients`
- Implement the [MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009669) (You don't actually have to but you **should**)
- Present the View Controller

You may also want to see a [question filled with great answers regarding sending text messages programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10848/2305521)!