# How to send SMS on the iPhone without pressing send button? (If just for demo, not for the Appstore)

Tags: ios, iphone, sms

I am working on an app that can automatically send a message to some specific ones (either emails or SMS) under some dangerous circumstances.

When someone is in danger, he or she has no time to press the send button. Is it possible for the user to approve sending messages in the app in advance, so the app can automatically send emails or SMS to others without telling the user?

I searched in StackOverflow, but found no similar answers.
This is just for a demo. It does not need to be approved by Apple.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

Comment: that is not possible with the public iOS SDK. But you could use a SMS provider like https://www.twilio.com/sms

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ChatKit](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/ChatKit.framework#Sending_a_Message_in_iOS_8) framework.
It uses iOS private APIs to do what you want to achieve. Don't try to submit it to Apple though.

With this framework, you can programmatically compose and send text messages through iMessage/SMS.