# Send SMS to user selected recipients via default messenger on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sms

There are multiple threads on stackoverflow, like this one: [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)
That discuss on how to send an SMS message to specified list of recipients. But I really need to somehow let the user select the recipients to share some info from my app (ideally I want also to show an image besides text body), is there a way to do this? I know I can do such a thing with Facebook SDK, but here I want to use SMS/default messenger. And I am using Objective C for my development.

Comment: Have you made any attempt with `MFMessageComposeViewController`? Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: I need to set up recipients that were selected by the user. This is the functionality I am looking for. Yes, I selected to use `MFMessageComposeViewController`, but in all of the examples I have seen on stackoverflow and elsewhere they do not mention `where` they get the phone numbers to send sms to, they just say how to set the numbers.

Comment: In other words, my issue is that I do not want to set the numbers myself, but by the user. I am confused about whether it is required to set the recipients or not.

Comment: Simply present the `MFMessageComposeViewController`. Don't set any recipients. Now see what the user can do. Try it.

Comment: `MFMessageComposeViewController ` draws contacts from a user's address book. It's the same interface as if you began drafting a new message in Messages.

Comment: @rmaddy, why do any work yourself? That's what we're for. <sigh>

Comment: I see, I do not know Messages. So, does it mean that I can just skip recipients part? Could you provide any links?

Comment: @Duncan C I do not ask for code, just for some guidance. I searched extensively online, not only on stackoverflow, and was not able to figure it out. That's why I am asking. Apple docs did not provide me with these details either.

Comment: @rmaddy OK, thank you! The method `[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]` returns `false` on the iOS simulator. That's the problem. Can I test it on the simulator (avoiding deprecated methods) ?

Comment: OK, I guess, not. I just want to test the functionality and do not have iPhone.

Comment: Some things have to be tested on real devices. In fact, the whole app really must be tested on a real device before you send the app to Apple.

Comment: This is not an app you can develop on the sim. You are going to need a device. You might borrow an older iPod touch, but you must have an iOS device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments said, `MFMessageComposeViewController` includes a built-in contact picker that's linked to the user's address book. If you already know the addresses of the recipients you'd like to send to, you can set `MFMessageComposeViewController` yourself. You could (for example) use the `AddressBook` framework and pull numbers out yourself, but that's going to involve:

1. Asking the user for permission
2. Displaying an interface for the user to select numbers
3. Feeding that information to `MFMessageComposeViewController`

I would avoid doing this unless you have a compelling reason to do so.

Here's an example that sends a message to two recipients along with a message and an attachment.

```
- (void)presentMessageViewController {

if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText] &&
    [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendAttachments]) {

    MFMessageComposeViewController *messageViewController = [MFMessageComposeViewController new];
    messageViewController.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    messageViewController.recipients = @[@"867-5309",
                                         @"1-800-MIX-A-LOT"];
    messageViewController.body = @"Hey, Jenny and Sir Mix-A-Lot!";
    [messageViewController addAttachmentData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Funny Cats"])
                              typeIdentifier:@"public.data"
                                    filename:@"image.png"];

    [self presentViewController:messageViewController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:^{
                         nil;
                     }];
    }
}
```

Again, unless you *already know* the addresses of recipients, the recipients property is optional. The user will input that information in `MFMessageComposeViewController` themselves.