# send a message through Xcode programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sms

I am trying to send a message through **Xcode** programmatically but when I click the send button it opens the message sending box. But I want to send message directly without opening message box. **Is this possible in iOS Xcode or not?** Please help me.[image: this is send button]

[image: when i click send button this is open sending message box]

**but don't want open sending message box.**

the code is

```
- (IBAction)sendSMS:(id)sender 
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = @"Hello  this is anup";
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"7026144009", nil];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}


- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    switch (result) 
    {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
        { 
            NSLog(@"faild");
            UIAlertController *alrt=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"my apps" message:@"unknown error" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
                //do something when click button
            }];
            [alrt addAction:okAction];
            break;
        }
        case MessageComposeResultSent:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Have you passed in this way for sending message..[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:+919999999999"]]

Comment: then create a own view and get all user details and finally sent the details to backend server, the backend server trigger the sms to the particular number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can u explain me in details please. because i don't have much more knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ya it is possible** on that your scenario no need of `MFMessageComposeViewController`, just one webservice is enough, send the two `(@"Hello  this is anup",@"7026144009")` to your backend , the backend developer send the `SMS` to that particular number using `SMTP Server` option.

**Choice -2**

if you want to handle in your own use some thirdparty SDK like [**skpsmtpmessage**](https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage), it work like same `SMTP`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't programatically send a message without the user's content.
The most you can do is open the messages app and if the user decides to send it, he can send it.

Comment: @anupgupta Nope... this is it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't programatically send a message without the user's consent. The most you can do, is open the messages app and if the user decides to send it, he can send it.

```
(IBAction)sendingMessage:(id)sender {

        MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
        {
            controller.body = @"SMS message here";
            controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"+919015156562", nil];
            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        }

}
```

And:

```
(void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller
didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```