# Send background sms ios 12

Tags: ios, swift

I know that iOS used to not allowing background sms.

However, I've come to cross the ["Shortcuts" app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/shortcuts/id915249334). In this app, you can send SMS without user interaction. I've search the internet but I am not sure whether there is a new api in ios 12 to send background sms.

Do you know if such an api is now available?

Comment: Please [search on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+send+sms+background), there are many existing questions.

Comment: _"you can send SMS without user interaction"_ – could you please elaborate this? just because in shortcut app (what is Apple own product / feature for iOS 12) the user explicitly needs to set up and allow the shortcut for messaging.

Comment: if you talking about real SMS - then only 3rd party service may help. (for example Twillio). Otherwise - it may be local (or not local) push notification

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that without MFMessageComposeViewController, it is restricted by apple so that you stay in control of your messages. [You can read this question for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)