# Problem publishing an app with SMS permissions

Tags: android, google-play

recently, the new Google policy doesn't allow the publishing of apps with SMS capabilities if they don't respect some features. Basically, all the apps that send and receive SMS are going to be removed or rejected during publication.

I'm producing an app that allow the user to control own programmable thermostat via SMS. The app exists since 2-3 years and it's used by 5000 customers.

With the new Google policy, they rejected my last app update. When I publish the update, the Google Console asks me to fill a declaration form for the SMS permission. I tried to fill the form more times, selecting different options, but they still continue to reject my app.
Moreover, other companies that develop the same identical app are publishing updates, so I don't understand why my application is rejected even if it's identical to other accepted apps.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Maybe did anyone have the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: read blog https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/reminder-smscall-log-policy-changes.html

Comment: [read on xda how tasker app gets approval](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-restriction-sms-call-log-permissions/)

Comment: Seems like we need to ditch playstore and try other markets.

Answer (score 1):

My app is an automatic REPLYER, it receives an SMS and if it is considered a VALID command automatically answers to the sender providing the GPS position via SMS, all in clear, the user hears and can see the messages both received and sent in his standard message archive .... in this way, an elder or an in-danger child can be reached at their position.

Why should there be no exception for these uses?
In the exception request form of google there is the entry "Emergency" but only provides for the exception for the SEND_SMS permission and not also for READ_SMS or RECEIVED_SMS .... but how can you send a text message a person who may have missed it, is fainted, it's dead ... it's absurd! It's obvious that there must be both permissions! ... if it's a third person to request the position as you can think of removing the permission "READ" ... the only explanation is that they do not know absolutely what they are doing.

Even I, like you, I do not know how to do it, they continually refuse my request for an exception, and I'm really angry because after years and years of refinements, tests, now I find myself being treated as a "scammer" or I do not know what else ... when I have always worked to make the app useful and clear.

Answer (score 0):

The root answer to this is sending SMS without visibility to the user is bad. For every app like yours, which does it for legitimate reasons, there are 1000s that try to defraud the user by sending SMS to premium rate numbers. So Google has clamped down.

iOS has had this banned for years, and [developers have found ways of coping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone). It is worth asking yourself how you would solve the same problem on iPhone.

You've got a few possible solutions:

- The [help centre page is here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303). For some purposes there is an exception. Unfortunately your use case is not on the list of permitted exceptions. So however you fill in the form, you are not going to be allowed to republish your app in the current form.
- Option 2 is to allow the user to confirm the SMS before sending. As described in the "alternatives to common usages" in the help center you can use [an SMS intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#SendMessage) to send an SMS which the user confirms
- If you need complete automation you only have one option left. Set up your own SMS sending server, that gets a message over the internet to send the SMS, then send using an online SMS sending service. There are quite a few.

I realize none of these match the convenience you have today. It was a hard call for Google but they made it to protect Android users from bad apps.